# SQL query when inner join value exists or doesn't

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
select 
    case when jp.IntValue = 0 then 'N' else 'Y' end 'Enabled',
    j.LastChange 'Last Changed',
    90 'Lookback History Days',
    max(h.StartTime) 'Last Run',
    j.JobName 'Job Name' 
from 
    Job j
inner join 
    JobProperty jp on jp.JobId = j.JobId and jp.PropertyId = 397
inner join 
    History h on h.JobId = j.JobId
group by 
    jp.IntValue, j.LastChange, j.JobName
```

What I want to be able to do is expand it like this:

```
select  
    case when (jp.IntValue = 0 or jp.IntValue not exists) then 'N' else 'Y' end 'Enabled',
    j.LastChange 'Last Changed',
    90 'Lookback History Days',
    max(h.StartTime) 'Last Run',
    j.JobName 'Job Name' 
from 
    Job j
full outer join 
    JobProperty jp on jp.JobId = j.JobId and jp.PropertyId = 397
inner join 
    History h on h.JobId = j.JobId
group by 
    jp.IntValue, j.LastChange, j.JobName
```

but I can't seem to make it work.

Essentially I want to join the table, but if the table can't join on the FK I want to still make note of the Job.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all jobs, then use `left join`:

```
select (case when jp.IntValue = 0 or jp.IntValue not exists) then 'N' else 'Y'
        end) as Enabled,
       j.LastChange as LastChanged,
       90 as LookbackHistoryDays,
       max(h.StartTime) as LastRun,
       j.JobName
from Job j left join
     JobProperty jp
     on jp.JobId = j.JobId and
        jp.PropertyId = 397 left join
     History h
     on h.JobId = j.JobId
group by (case when jp.IntValue = 0 or jp.IntValue not exists) then 'N' else 'Y'
          end), j.LastChange, j.JobName
```